# Adding rel: 'nofollow, noindex' at once to link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, seo

In my Rails application I would like to add `nofollow, noindex` to few links. However I am  not sure whether I need to add `comma(,)` or not.

Which one is correct ?

```
1. <%= link_to 'Apply', apply_new_path, rel: 'nofollow, noindex' %> # with comma(,)

or

2. <%= link_to 'Apply', apply_new_path, rel: 'nofollow noindex' %> # no comma(,) used here
```

Answer (score 1):

> The rel attribute on a and area elements controls what kinds of links the elements create. The attribute's value must be an unordered set of unique **space-separated** tokens.
>
> - [WHATWG - HTML
>   Living Standard : links](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/links.html#linkTypes)

Comment: Note that Rails is kind of irrelevant here - `link_to` just takes any of the options in  the `html_options` hash with are not `data`, `method` or `remote` and makes them into HTML attributes by calling `to_s`.